# Unable to create "SS" AttributeValue for DynamoDB query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to perform a query in AWS DynamoDB using "dynamodb-doc". My NodeJS code looks like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const DOC = require('dynamodb-doc');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({});
const docMyTable = DOC.DynamoDB(dynamodb);

var CodeSet = ['code01', 'code02', 'code03'];
var queryParams = {TableName: 'my-table'}
queryParams.KeyConditions = [docMyTable.Condition("code", "IN", CodeSet)];
docMyTable.query(queryParams, (err, data) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

AWS docs for Condition can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html). It specifies that for the ComparisonOperator "IN", an "array of Strings" is supported but I get the following error:

> ComparisonOperator IN is not valid for L AttributeValue type

Am I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the SET using the `docClient.Set` method. As long as the `code` is defined as SET in DyanmoDB table, the below solution may resolve the problem.

```
var DOC = require("dynamodb-doc");
var docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();
docClient.Set(["a", "b", "c"], "S")
```

> IN : Checks for matching elements within two sets.

Comment: Thank you @notionquest this worked for me

Comment: Good. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.